# Intellij does not show any errors in the syntax/does not give any suggestions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, sdk, ide

There's a couple of similar threads, but none seems to contain the answer to my issue.

My IDE does not show any error, does not give any suggestions, does not import anything. Example:

```
public static String createInversion(ArrayList<String> splitName) {
        splitName.removeIf(n -> List.of("Lord", "Lady").contains(n));
        ArrayList<String> reverted = List.newArrayList(splitName.stream()
        .collect(Collector.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
        .descendingIterator());
        return String.format("%s, %s", splitName.get(1), splitName.get(0));
        gyugyuihu
                dsfsdf
                rewfewr
    }
```

You can clearly see that the last three lines are random chains of letters without any context. My IDE does not highlight them, does not report any problems. I don't even know if I should use Collector or Collectors class, because I am given zero suggestions, it's like writing in a Word Document.

I am only given errors the moment I try to compile, but also just in the terminal. The code remains untouched by Intellij.

I do not have the Power Safe Mode on, SDK is set correctly, language level in Modules is set correctly, Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Java Compiler -> Target Bytecode Version is set correctly, the main folder is marked as the Source Root.

I am out of ideas. Please help.

EDIT:
Adding a screenshot of my setup.
[image]

Comment: Three notes: Your method should accept `List<String>` instead of requiring `ArrayList` specifically, it is not polite to modify the input, and your reversing logic is unnecessarily complicated. Instead, you can say `Collections.reverse(splitName.filter(n -> !LORD_LADY.contains(n)).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new)))`.

Comment: Thanks, I will modify my code. :-) Alas, that's beside my main problem. I don't even know what options I have because my IDE acts as if it was "turned off".

Comment: A bit hard to tell without seeing the setup. Is the file part of the project, meaning - is it in the src folder of any of your modules? How have you imported the project, is it maven, groovy, sbt?

Comment: I added a screenshot with my setup. The file is a part of the project, it's in the proper folder. The project is mine and built with Maven. The thing is - it worked without problems before. It's just that everything was fine and when I open it the next day - it's malfunctional like that. You can see it technically highlights the class name in the upper bar, but does not touch the code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to invalidate the caches? That usually clears up issues like this. It's easy to do too: From the main menu, select File | Invalidate Caches / Restart.

Comment: Lilith almighty, it worked <3 Thank you soooo muuuch <3

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above try to do invalidate caches/Restart( File -> invalidate caches/Restart)

If it did not work then check pom file name is not strikethrough. If pom file has strikethrogh then
IntelljIdea -> Select Build,Execution,Deployment -> Select Build Tools -> maven  -> Select Ignored Files - Check pom is present in ignore file. If yes then uncheck it . and do mvn clean install